# Alter Table fails because a row has incorrect data - Incorrect datetime value: '0000-00-00 00:00:00'

Tags: mysql, datetime

I am updating the current user table with the following statement:

```
`ALTER TABLE  `users` ADD  `title` VARCHAR( 5 ) NULL DEFAULT NULL AFTER  `surname` ;`
```

Which returns the following error:

`#1292 - Incorrect datetime value: '0000-00-00 00:00:00' for column 'created_at' at row 1`

Created_at column structure is:

`created_at datetime NOT NULL`

Not sure why the data is invalid - could it be related to MySQL versions (from 5.5.43 into 5.1.73)?

The fix I have at the moment is to update the datetime value before the ALTER TABLE statement:

```
UPDATE `users` SET `created_at`='2014-01-01 00:00:00' WHERE `created_at`='0000-00-00 00:00:00';
```

Is this a reasonable workaround?

Comment: Seems perfectly reasonable to me.

Comment: Please add the output of `SELECT @@SQL_MODE, @@VERSION;`

Answer (score 6):

you should disable STRICT_TRANS_TABLES mode

```
SET sql_mode = '';
```

or
go to `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` & comment out `STRICT_TRANS_TABLES`

**useful note** [SQL STRICT MODE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sql-mode-strict)

Answer (score 3):

[MySQL's docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/datetime.html) say

> The server requires that month and day values be valid, and not merely
>   in the range 1 to 12 and 1 to 31, respectively.

Also:

> With strict mode enabled, invalid dates generate an error. To permit
>   such dates, enable ALLOW_INVALID_DATES.

So [Michael - sqlbot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30571754/alter-table-fails-because-a-row-has-incorrect-data-incorrect-datetime-value/37054866#comment49273846_30571754) was asking you the right question.

Answer (score 2):

> Created_at column structure is:
>   `created_at datetime NOT NULL`

It would seem that '0000-00-00 00:00:00' is treated as NULL in your new MySQL version but not your old one, and you've specified that the DB shouldn't accept NULL values ("NOT NULL").